# Не может прочесть аудио файл в питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Решилка я  создать себе телеграм бота, хотя питон учу макс.несколько дней.И вот захотел чтобы мой бот смог переводить голосовые сообщения в текстовые и тут возникла проблема.Текст ошибки:**Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format.**Хотя на компе аудиофайл существует и даже тот , что  я отправлял как голосовое сообщение боту в телеге.
Вот код,где ,как я думаю ,есть ошибка:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice'])
def record_voice(message):
    ids=message.voice.file_id
    path=bot.get_file(ids).file_path
    files=open('D:/Bot/voice.wav',"wb")
    url=requests.get("https://api.telegram.org/file/bot"+token+"/"+path)
    files.write(url.content)
    files.close()
    record_audio('D:/Bot/voice.wav')
def record_audio(path):
    sample_audio = sr.AudioFile(path)
    with sample_audio as audio_file:
        audion_content = recog.record(audio_file)
    result=recog.recognize_google(audion_content)
    send_echo(result)
```

Заранее благодарю.И ,если можете , то скажите пожалуйста можно ли как как-то подругому сделать перевод из голосового в текстовое , а то мне чет не очень нравится такая реализация.

Answer (score 0):

Ваше исключение генерируется по причине неправильного формата файла, несмотря на разрешение `.wav` ваш файл находится в формате `.WebM`, исходя из этого и генерируется данной исключение. Чтобы вам "не наступать на одни и те же грабли" могу посоветовать проверять формат файла , к примеру так  `name.wav: WebM`. Для записи `.wav` вам необходимо установить `MediaRecorder.mimeType` документация для него -> [Здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder).